# Who causes this "502 Bad Gateway nginx"?

Tags: nginx, redirect, cloudflare

I recently started using SendPulse.com for sending email campaigns to a list of thousands of recipients.

Sometimes my email campaigns have contained links, such as to a post on Facebook.

SendPulse is supposed to track which recipients click which links.

To do this, before sending out my email campaign, they replace the URLs in the message with URLs that go to their systems, which can record the tracking and then redirect the visitors to the real destination.

Unfortunately, these redirect links often do not work. We've frequently been seeing this error `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`:

[image: 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)]

Here is the HTML of that page:

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

It occurs to me that the root cause of the problem could be within SendPulse, CloudFlare (which we use for DNS), or Facebook.

We know it's not browser-specific, and we know that visitors from different parts of the world have experienced this problem.

It seems highly unlikely that CloudFlare¹ or Facebook would frequently throw this error.

**Are there certain commands (maybe related to `traceroute`?) that could identify who is throwing the error (SendPulse, CloudFlare, Facebook, or someone else)?**

¹<sub>By the way, [CloudFlare docs](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003011431#h_85e06a1a-fa89-4685-aa24-2aaf57c0141b) say: "If the error does not mention “cloudflare,” contact your hosting provider for assistance on 502/504 errors from your origin." But in CloudFlare, my subdomain is set to "DNS only" (gray cloud) instead of "Proxied" (orange cloud). I don't know whether these docs apply to a subdomain set to "DNS only".</sub>

Comment: The HTML plays no part in this problem. This is a server configuration error.

Comment: @Rob Yep, I know; I was just posting the HTML to show that I could see no hidden hints about who was serving it.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to comment on how I could improve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the link that occasionally fails is `mysubdomain.mydomain.com/abc`, and if my CloudFlare DNS shows a CNAME entry for `mysubdomain.mydomain.com` to point to `track.stat-pulse.com`, then a screenshot of `track.stat-pulse.com/abc` throwing the 502 error is (probably? Unless I'm misunderstanding something) enough to prove that the SendPulse servers are causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

If the `sp.` subdomain points in DNS to SendPulse, then obviously that's where the errors happen and you don't need (and can't) traceroute anything.

Comment: Well, I'd *assume* I could rule out Facebook since the error page does not have facebook.com in the URL. But I don't understand how I could rule out CloudFlare (who manages my DNS) because what if CloudFlare occasionally fails to resolve this subdomain to SendPulse? I know it seems highly unlikely. It seems to me that SendPulse is the problem even though they refuse to admit it. But my question is how I can *prove* that the error is in SendPulse's servers.